# Downloading workflow dependencies on demand for the client

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4

Figure 9 from article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835242.aspx  describe 'Logical flow for downloading workflow dependencies on demand for the client.' How can it be technically implemented? Handle AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event? Or is there other solution?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily WF4 related.

Any application can listen for the AssemblyResolve event (it *is* an event on the `AppDomain` type), check for the assembly in the list of assemblies available on, say, for example, nuget.org, and then handle the downloading and loading of that assembly at runtime.

I don't believe there are other solutions (and wouldn't assume that I could answer better than a search engine), as this is not the most common behavior in applications.

Comment: Hello Will. I know that any application can listen for the AssemblyResolve event. I just was wondering if some special mechanism for resolving assembly is foreseen in Workflow Designer Loader.

Comment: @DmitryPhilippov: Hmm, I do think that the xaml loader has hooks for resolving assemblies by xaml namespace.  Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Yes, this is I actually asked. Thanks for restating my question.

Comment: @DmitryPhilippov: Nope, not what you asked.  You said "want do figure nine how".  There was no "I need to intercept xml namespace resolution at deserialization time so I can load assemblies from a remote location."  Nevertheless, you'll have to deserialize workflows before passing them to the designer, as you can't touch the process otherwise.  [Look at this namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.xamlintegration(v=vs.110).aspx) and see if there's anything you can hook into. If not, parse the namespaces yourself, then load assemblies, then load the workflow.